# Integral of this function

Tags: integration

I would like to take the integral of the following function:

$$ \int_{0}^{x} \frac{1}{\sqrt{u}(1+\sqrt{u})} du$$

I try the substituttion $$w = 1+\sqrt{u}$$, and I got the result as follows, is this right or wrong?

$$ 2[\ln|1+\sqrt{x}|]$$

Comment: Can you share what you've tried? This should be shouting "substitution."

Comment: I guess you missed a $\mathrm{d}u$ somewhere. Otherwise, yeah, substitution!

Comment: Try the substitution $w = 1 + \sqrt{u}$.  What happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the substitution $w=1+\sqrt{u},\,dw=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{u}}du$ to see that the integral turns into $\int_1^{1+\sqrt{x}}\frac{2}{w}dw$, which is easy to evaluate as $\int\frac{1}{w}dw=\ln|w|+C$.

Comment: Is your $$dw$$ right? I think it should be $$1/2\sqrt{u}$$

Comment: Yes, that was a mistake.

Comment: Your answer is correct.